# React Redux Problem: How to call multiple api in your react component with React Redux Toolkit RTK queries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rtk-query

Hope you all are doing fine.

RTK queries return response in data attribute which can be accessed via hook generated by RTK

My Code:

```
const {data = [], isFetching} = useFetchConversationQuery(categoryId, {
    skip
});
const { data } = useFetchCategoryQuery();
```

My issue is that I'm trying to call 2 RTK queries in a react component so there cant be two attribute with the same name is there a way to change the name of data attribute in RTK queries,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's no way to change the RTK data attribute name, however what you can instead do is simply assign a different name when you destructure your object.

```js
const {data = [], isFetching} = useFetchConversationQuery(categoryId, {
    skip
});
const { data: myNewDataName } = useFetchCategoryQuery();

myNewDataName // data from useFetchCategoryQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have realized this limitation. This is not exactly what you are looking for but you can use them like this;

```
const conversation = useFetchConversationQuery(categoryId, {
    skip
});
const category = useFetchCategoryQuery();

// conversation.data.map(item=>console.log(item._id));
// console.log(category.data)
```